# Visited Days vs Consecutive Days

Tags: support, consecutive-days, visited-days

I noticed that there is a `Visited` section on my profile today. It says `visited    39 days, 24 consecutive` and I have been a `member for 39 days`.

Can anyone explain to me how this works? Shouldn't I have 39 consecutive days if I visited the site every day since I signed up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your profile, you registered on May 13th, 2010 at 13:55:54. This is actually 40 days from today since the count is inclusive, but it may have said "39 days" for the period where a full day had not accumulated. So, basically, you missed one day 24 days ago.

In fact, right now, it says "member for 40 days", because the system clock only recently passed 13:55:54.

Comment: I don't know at what time I did register, but it always shows me yesterday's values when I go to the profile page for the first time of a day. When I go to another page and then go back to the profile, the values are updated. This is the same for all sites I've registered with.