# Implementation date for the consecutive days calendar

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I just discovered the neat calendar that displays on which days one was active (illustrated below). When was this feature announced and/or implemented?

---

## Before


[image]

---

## After

[image]

Comment: I think you just announced it. Congratulations!

Answer (score 10):

Woohoo!

Now can we please make it discoverable so [th](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29225/how-many-days-left-to-visit-the-site-in-order-to-earn-fanatic-badge-closed)[ere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49576/etiquette-question-is-there-a-way-to-contact-moderators-for-specific-reputation) [wo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54581/visited-days-vs-consecutive-days)[n't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear) [be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55757/how-did-my-consecutive-day-count-jump-from-21-to-12-closed) [so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/stackoverflow-claims-i-broke-my-consecutive-visit-streak-i-know-i-didnt) [ma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57750/consecutive-day-reset)[ny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/consecutive-day-count-reset-this-morning) [sup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97)[port](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66526/consecutive-days-is-flawed) [ques](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67191/lost-consecutive-days-status-closed)[tio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67161/consecutive-days-bug-glitch)[ns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68026/did-something-cut-visited-consecutive-days-at-so-recently)

Comment: At least some explaining text should be displayed when the cursor is over that area.

Comment: A little [ + ] beside of it would explain it well enough

Comment: For those reading back, Jeff has said this is likely going to stay as an easter egg.