# Could the "consecutive days calendar" link be more obvious?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, consecutive-days

This morning, I've quite accidentally discovered [this question, which revealed the Consecutive Days Calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/implementation-date-for-the-consecutive-days-calendar). The calendar is a great addition, thank you, SO Team!

I have a suggestion though: Could the calendar be a bit more discoverable, please?

To wit, I've been looking at that exact text for months, and apparently the calendar has been available for several weeks now, I would never have guessed it even exists - the page gives no indication the text is somehow special, except the cursor changing to "hand" on mouseover.

I do remember reading [something](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/11/dont-click-here-the-art-of-hyperlinking.html) about "not hiding your links" - if the text is supposed to initiate an action, could it be underlined, or else somehow differentiated from normal text? (in that question, [@Bryan Denny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/396/bryan-denny) suggests "A little [ + ] beside of it would explain it well enough")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as an [easter egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media))!

Comment: All right then. I've seen Easter Eggs in various software, but this may be the first recorded instance of a Halloween Egg :o)