# 'Hidden' links on profile page

Tags: discussion, profile-page, design

I just noticed that I can click on the visited and recent names part in profiles by accident.

Is this by design because they are javascript stuff? If this is the case I suggest to make it look like it's clickable by styling it using javascript. This way the items will still look static when someone has js disabled.

[image: Hidden links of profile page]

Comment: Related: [Hidden features of Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow/69632#69632)

Comment: @Arjan So it is meant to be an easter egg?

Comment: @PeeHaa I would call it a feature, not an easter egg.

Comment: Pure design. [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/119949/timeline) can be considered Easter Egg - showing information that is not linked from anywhere. :)

Comment: The "visited" apparently is an official [easter egg](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70762/could-the-consecutive-days-calendar-link-be-more-obvious/70768#70768)...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been addressed at some point since the question of asked, by including a Calendar icon next to the text.

[image]

Clicking the icon or anywhere on the text will now open the Calendar view of days visited.