# How can I see which days I visited site?

Tags: support, visited-days, calendar

- How can I see which days I visited site MSO or SO?
- Is there any method, list or calendar view?

Comment: This is, incidentally, [an official Easter Egg](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70762/could-the-consecutive-days-calendar-link-be-more-obvious/70768#70768). Good day to find it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go you your profile page and click on the number of days you've visited:

[image]

You'll then see a calendar. The days you've visited are in green:

[image]

You can navigate back through the calendar in the usual way.

Click outside the calendar to dismiss it.

Comment: How crazy below that text is calendar! That text should have different color.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - well the cursor does change to a hand when your mouse rolls over the text...

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes cursor changes to pointer on hover. But on hover...I could have imagined to hover on it.

Comment: @Somnath, many things on SE show more details when hovering. Like all dates (and "xx hours ago") show the full date in the tooltip, or hovering a name shows the reputation. And there are many more ["hidden" features](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-overflow).

Comment: Also hovering on a gravatar of a 1K+ user shows the [expanded usercard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user)...

Comment: @ChrisF When did the days visited switch from green to grey? Thinking about it, bringing back green would be nice, but only for days you earned rep (and un-outlined green for days you earned rep but didn't visit)

Comment: @TylerH I hadn't noticed.

Comment: @ChrisF Oof, I forgot that you were a moderator and not an employee. My bad!

Answer (score 6):

Well, since ChrisF has stated that [he is not interested in any more MSO rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128605/how-can-i-see-which-days-i-visited-site#comment351115_128606) - I thought my answer might also assist the OP :P

As you can see in the diagram's below - clicking on the visited/consecutive information in your profile will give you a calendar.  On that calendar, each day that was visited is marked in green.

[image]

<sup>Days where you had a exceptionally good time on the site *might* be highlighted with free hand smiley faces.  Too much meta may result in a free hand red mustache.</sup>

Comment: Is there any way to make white boxes green!!!! Some sundays made my memory loss to visit SO & MSO.-:-(

Comment: Going for that [fanatic badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/53/fanatic)? hehe :P Um - no, if you did not visit the site on one day it resets the "consecutive days" counter...

Comment: Sure it's possible, @SomnathMuluk, all you need is a good time machine.

Comment: Worst uses for a time machine #56 - Travel back in time because you forgot to log into SO for the fanatic badge.

Comment: @man - your custom comment reply script works well :P

Comment: @Lix Great! Now you can be meta-lazy while commenting! :P