# How to close consecutive days calendar in my user profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, consecutive-days

[image]

Hey! I cannot find the switch to close the calendar. When I click on *Visited: 321 days, 3 consecutive*, it [pop ups the calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/implementation-date-for-the-consecutive-days-calendar). But I cannot close it. (Is refresh the only way to close it?)

Comment: +1. I came here to ask this same question! :)

Comment: And I've never known about this calendar until now. :-)

Comment: @Jamal rule #1: click everywhere, sometimes you'll be pleasantly surprised. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any - the only way to get rid of it is to refresh or navigate to a different page.

As with other things which might be considered minor annoyances, the easiest way to get this functionality is to write a GreaseMonkey script for it.

Comment: Amazing, not only did they skimp out on the close button, they hired a blind man to style it.

Comment: @Nick: Are you saying 'the close button 1) is not there at all, plus 2) it looks awful'? :D But I agree, that green-and-grey look is not really consistent with the rest of the site.

Comment: I didn't see a close button, doesn't really need one honestly, but like you said, the bright green is inconsistent. I think it should have been orange personally.

Answer (score 5):

As Piskvor has said there isn't a built in way to do this but if you copy this JavaScript  to your toolbar it will close the calendar for you.

```
javascript:(function(){

$('#calendar').remove(); 
$('#days-visited').bind('click', loadCalendar); 
$('#days-visited').css('cursor', 'pointer');


})();
```

Encoded version

```
javascript:(function()%7B%20%20%09$('#calendar').remove();%20%20%09$('#days-visited').bind('click',%20loadCalendar);%20%20%09$('#days-visited').css('cursor',%20'pointer');%20%20%20%09%7D)();
```

Answer (score 4):

Clicking somewhere other than the calendar seems to work for me as of now (Dec 14-13).

Comment: Yeah, for me it was always like this from the very first time I checked  (about three years ago) so guess it was fixed shortly after this report.

Comment: Works now for me in Firefox, but did _not_ work about six months ago.