# How to close the calender in the User's profile page

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close consecutive days calendar in my user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72994/how-to-close-consecutive-days-calendar-in-my-user-profile)

Just want to know when I click on the visited link in profile page, a **Calender** opens which shows x days and y consecutive days I have visited the site **BUT**,

[image]

I didn't find any option to close the calender. **Is it a Bug** ? or am I missing something.