# Calendar Should have close button

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to close consecutive days calendar in my user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72994/how-to-close-consecutive-days-calendar-in-my-user-profile)

I don't know whether it is the right place to ask the question what i am going to say is when user clicks on Days a calendar is popping up but there is no close option for that so can any one fix this